# count of last item of the day

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a query in which one of the fields contains the count of status. The status can change several times a day and the count should be based on the final status of the day. For instance, this is what I have for Status1.

```
CountStatus1 = (from status in MyDataContext.StatusHistory
     where status.UserID == TheUserID
     where status.StatusDateTime.Month == TheMonth.Month
     where status.StatusDateTime.Year == TheMonth.Year
     where status.NewStatus == 1 // where the LAST STATUS OF THE DAY == 1
     select status.StatusID).Count()
```

The problem is that I want to select the **last** status of the day to be equal to 1, and count those. The status for a day can change from 1 to 4 to 2 to 5 to 3 and then to finally to 1; if I write the query like this, the count will include 2 1's and then the 4,2,5 and 3 will also be counted in CountStatus4, CountStatus3, CountStatus"n".

The return data is a monthly report grouped by day, where each day is a row.

The structure of the query looks like this:

```
var OutputStatusReport = from w in MyDataContext.WorkHistory
    where w.UserID == TheUserID
    where w.WorkDatetime.Month == TheMonth.Month
    where w.WorkDatetime.Year == TheMonth.Year
    group w by w.Datetime.Date into daygroups
    select new MyObjectModel
    {
         CountStatus1 = ....,
         CountStatus2 = ....,
         CountStatus3 =......
    };
```

So I need the day of the count to match the day of daygroups.

I'm struggling to figure this one out and any help is very welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a set operations question, and there are a couple ways to do this:

1) For each instance where there could be multiple conditions, only select the condition where the value is what you actually wanted

Select myDesiredInformation 
from tables 
where allMyOtherConditions and 
**MyMultipleCondition = MAX(select allCases of the multiple condition)**

2) Join the table on itself, comparing the multiple conditions, and take the one that meets your desired criteria

select myDesiredInformation 
from theTableWithMultipleConditions t1 left outer join theTableWithMultipleConditions t2
where allMyOtherConditions and 
**t1.MagicValue > t2.MagicValue and t2.value is null**

There are other ways, but one of these will likely be enough to solve the problem you have described.

---

### EDIT: in response to your comments

```
var query = from status in MyDataContext.StatusHistory
            where status.UserID == TheUserID
            where status.StatusDateTime.Month == TheMonth.Month
            where status.StatusDateTime.Year == TheMonth.Year
            where status.NewStatus == 1 
            where status.StatusUpdateTime == (
                 from status in MyDataContext.StatusHistory
                 where (all those conditions above)
                 select status.StatusUpdateTime).Max()
            select status.StatusID
```

This would implement it like #1 and you can see implementing it like #2 is not that much different.

Comment: @frenchie edited to give you a head start.  Now that I am thinking about it, how do you track which status happened last?

Comment: by the time the status happened: Status.Datetime records the change time and Status.NewStatus is the status that's updated to. So I was thinking about using the Max in a lambda function but I'm not getting it to work.

Comment: Ok, so I implemented your solution and, it works!!!! No runtime errors; I'll do the testing against the dummy data in a bit to test the results of the query. Thank you very much!